# Knockout js, accessing observables out side the loop

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Consider the following example:

```
var something = ko.observableArray([{name: bob}, {name: sally}]);

<div data-bind="foreach: something"></div>
```

Inside this `div` I can do something like: `<p data-bind="text: name"></p>`

But what if I had another `ko.observerableArray`:

```
var another = ko.observableArray([{age: 22}, {age: 33}]);

<div data-bind="foreach: something">
  <p data-bind="text: name"> </p>
  // How do I access another? When I do:

  <div data-bind="foreach: another">
    <p data-bind="age"> </p>
  </div>

  // I get, another is not defined    
</div>
```

**How do I access a second `ko.observableArray`** inside the first loop of a `ko.observableArray` ??**

Comment: `$parent.another` or `$root.another`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the context property to get a property or function from parent binding for example `$root.foo` where foo  can be a function or an observable.
See the documentation in the ko web site:

> A binding context is an object that holds data that you can reference from your bindings. While applying bindings, Knockout automatically creates and manages a hierarchy of binding contexts. The root level of the hierarchy refers to the viewModel parameter you supplied toko.applyBindings(viewModel). Then, each time you use a control flow binding such aswith or foreach, that creates a child binding context that refers to the nested view model data.
>   Bindings contexts offer the following special properties that you can reference in any binding.
>   Ref. [KO Binding contexts](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

Comment: So for a select element would it be: `<select class="donor-js-wid-frequency" name="gift_freq" data-bind="options: $parent.frequencies, optionsText: $parent.frequencies.desc, value: $parent.frequencies.desc"></select>` or .... Did I miss something

Comment: But you can see something about the ````with```` binding,

Comment: @KyleAdams please if it is the correct answer mark as that. XD